# Homework guidance

Tags: discussion

I don't know where else to place this comment because I think I deleted my earlier question.  This afternoon I asked a question about whether or not it was feasible for a gust of wind to alter the course of a car in a 48 ft. flyover.    The responses I received were very nasty.  Posters were quick to tell me they wouldn't help me, that the accident was strictly my husband's fault, they wouldn't help me in court, etc.  I posed a question here because I thought that those who were gifted in math and sciences would help me.  Instead, I was made out to feel as if I were some sort of criminal and that my husband was totally at fault for an accident.  I was not asking anyone to testify in court; all I wanted to know if it/the wind could have been responsible for the car moving leaving the lane.  Might I ask of you that, in the event someone like me asks a question like this, would you at the very least treat that person with some respect....something that I was never shown.  Thank you.

Comment: [Link to other question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257775/help-me-get-out-of-a-traffic-ticket) (not visible to everyone).

Comment: It actually [takes 5 rep to post to meta](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) so a completely new poster has no recourse but to take advice from the comments until they can accumulate the requisite points (albeit a task requiring a singe vote on any post).

Comment: *"Instead, I was made out to feel as if I were some sort of criminal"* -  voting to close for the reason of criminal hyperbole.

Answer (score 7):

The comments on the deleted question were:

- I've flagged this question for removal because it is simply not about physics. This website is not meant to provide justice to those who may have been potentially wronged by the traffic authorities. – Eh-whaaa 9 hours ago
- Perhaps the question could be rephrased along the lines "What factors would cause a car of mass 3100 lbs travelling and is hit by a gust of wind ...." – jim 9 hours ago
- I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not court appointed expert witnesses and we can not help with legal matters. – CuriousOne 9 hours ago

These don't seem particularly malicious to me. I should add it's possible that a moderator may have deleted more offensive comments.

Comment: I did delete some additional comments - none of them were especially offensive, I thought, but they were less constructive.

Answer (score 5):

The kind of help you're seeking is not within the scope of this site. Specifically, we don't offer "calculational services" where you present the particulars of some situation and somebody completes the calculation for you. This is a website for people who are interested in physics as an intellectual endeavor, and the questions we accept are those which serve that purpose; what you're asking is not such a question.

We have [resources for new members](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) which explain this. Posting a question which clearly does not fit our scope shows a lack of respect for the site, and one might think, if you come into our community and don't show respect to us, why should we show respect to you? I'm not saying one is necessarily *right* to think this way, but it is a natural and common viewpoint.

We do have a rule that members are required to act with basic civility at all times. I've reviewed the comments on your post, and they don't violate that guideline. If people are saying they won't help you, or that the accident was your husband's fault, that may not be what you want to hear (and it probably would have been better for them to avoid commenting on the details of your situation), but it's not inherently rude or offensive.